# JavaScript Arithmetic's

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I am wondering this code, trying to understand the nan or Nan value since it is not falsy or truthy and it's just a Number object of the type of number,  the question is here why does this return zero since Nan is not falsy

my expected value here is Nan

```
    tip = '.'
    total = 10
    let totalPlusTip = ((total * (tip/100)) + total) || 0
    console.log(totalPlusTip) //0
```

my expected value here is 110

```
    tip = 10
    total = 100
    let totalPlusTip = ((total * (tip/100)) + total) || 0
    console.log(totalPlusTip) //110
```

since Nan is not false why isn't returning Nan
when we do

Comment: `since Nan is not falsy` But it **is** [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy)

Comment: Really can you please point me to documentation on that if available so I can understand further

Comment: Here you are: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy

Comment: Thank you very much, i searched for this on google, all i saw was Nan is not falsy, but your comment has been very helpful. and yes Nan is truly falsy

Comment: You could also do `!!NaN` in your browser console to see that it evaluates to `false`

Answer (score 1):

The reason why the first code output 0 is because NaN is false and in `||` operator, the  Logical OR operator `||` returns the value of its second operand, if the first one is false.

You could see below, the value of `((total * (tip/100)) + total)` is `NaN` and `!NaN` return true which means is return false. Since `NaN` is false, `||` return the second value which is 0.

```js
  let tip = '.'
   let total = 10
    let totalPlusTip = ((total * (tip/100)) + total) || 0
  console.log(total * (tip/100))
  console.log(!NaN)
    console.log(totalPlusTip) //0
```

Comment: Thank you, my confusion was i thought Nan isn't falsy but now i get the whole scope

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, It's falsy.

However, you can use Nullish coalescing operator (??) if you don't care about IE.

```js
let totalPlusTip = ((total * (tip/100)) + total) ?? 0
```

Only null or undefined will be 0.

Comment: alright thanks the problem was my mis understanding of the Nan value , its also falsy